# Название и назначение крючка, привинченного к колонне

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется этот крючок, ввинченный в колонну с помощью гайки?

Answer (score 2):

> Как называется этот крючок, ввинченный в колонну с помощью гайки?

Не крючок. Форма завершение винта — кольцо, петля. Анкер и винт в сборе — анкерный болт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]